# Return an in memory file in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to return a *BinaryFileResponse* response in a *Symfony* *Controller* but it asks for a *path* or a *File* object. The thing is that I'm getting the file over a *SOAP* service, and it creates an object like this: `filename` + `base64 encoded content` + `mime` + `extra stuff`.

I don't really want to save it to disk then create the response...

Maybe I'm blinded at the moment, but is there any way to send it without creating a file in disk?

This is the action:

```
public function downloadAction($hash){
   $document = $this->get('soap_services.document_service')->findDocument($hash);

   return $this->file($SymfonyFileObjectOrPath, $fileName);
}
```

The `$document` object offers the following relevant methods: *getMime*, *getName*, *getContent*.

That's what I want to use to make a response without creating a *File* object (and the physical file that it implies).

Comment: You may try to create a physical file but in the `shm`, it is just a `vfs` in memory.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Hello maybe you should consider to just give a Response and force the download "manually".

```
// Generate response
$response = new Response();
$filename = 'yourFileName.txt';

// Set headers
$response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'private');
$response->headers->set('Content-type', $yourMimeType );
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');
$response->headers->set('Content-length',  strlen($yourContentString));

// Send headers before outputting anything
$response->sendHeaders();

$response->setContent( $yourContentString );

return $response;
```

Maybe something like this will do the trick.
Can you try this, maybe change it a little bit?

Comment: Wow, it was obvious, I as blinded by the BinaryResponse... this did the trick perfectly.

Comment: I needed to write `$response->sendContent();` before return too.

Comment: I got HTTP 502 (bad gateway) using this for Symfony 6.2.14. What helped is removal of `$response->sendHeaders();` and `$response->sendContent();` so a bit opposite advice than previous comment.